# Separating light by polarization

Tags: optics, photons

When you let a light beam going through a polarizing filter 50% of the light will go through in a polarization oriented the same way as the filter and the 50 other percents will be absorbed.

My question is :

Is there a way to separate a lightbeam without losint thos 50%? I mean for example that 50% would go through the filter or this hypothetical device and the 50 other percents would be reflected or redirected. Therefore having in the end 1 beam that is separated in 2 beams with different polarization without losing any photons.

I don't know if this exists or even if this is even possible... so this is my question : is it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is . It is called a [polarizing beamsplitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Beam-splitting_polarizers).